# Updatepanel Update() from code file that is not inherited

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, vbscript, updatepanel

I have 4 files.. page.aspx and page.aspx.vb. Then control.aspx and control.aspx.vb. Page.aspx inherits its vb code file as control.aspx does.

I have a button on control.aspx. When I click that button I want to call UpdatePanelId1.Update(). Problem is that this Updatepanel with id UpdatePanelId1 is on page.aspx Not control.aspx. So how can page.aspx inherit two code files or access this UpdatePanelId1 from control files?

Simply put, UpdatePanelId1 on page.aspx is inaccessible/unreachable from the button click on control.aspx which is the call to the button click function stored in page.aspx.vb whose purpose is to UpdatePanelId1.Update().

Here is control.aspx..

```
<asp:Button id="btnUpdate" runat ="server" Text="" />
```

This is in control.aspx.vb..

```
Protected Sub ButtonClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnUpdate.Click
   UpdatePanelId1.Update() 'Needs to happen when there is that button click in control.aspx
   'UpdatePanelId1 is not accessible though since UpdatePanelId1 is in page.aspx
   'Visual Studio editor underlines UpdatePanelId1 because inaccessible
End Sub
```

Here is page.aspx..

```
<asp:ScriptManager runat="server" id="ScriptManager1"></asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" id="UpdatePanelId1">
<ContentTemplate> Whatever content that gets updated
</ContentTemplate> 
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Nothing revelent in page.aspx.vb to solving this problem.

Comment: you could use a site.master page for the updatepanel

Comment: @Cerveser will you please explain more? I had to look up what that was even.

Comment: Have you consider putting the control.aspx into a user control and then placing that inside page.aspx update panel?